# CSS3 Transition not working in IE, Firefox, Opera and Safari

Tags: html, css

For some reason I can't get the transitions to work.

There is supposed to be a transition when you hove over either section. Code is there, but it'll only work in Chrome.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

This is just on of the transitions that wont work.

```
-webkit-transition-property: translateY, skew; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s; 
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.02s;
-moz-transition-property: translateY, skew; 
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s; 
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease;
-moz-transition-delay: 0.02s;
-ms-transition-property: translateY, skew; 
-ms-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s; 
-ms-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease;
-ms-transition-delay: 0.02s;
-o-transition-property: translateY, skew; 
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
-o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease;
-o-transition-delay: 0.02s;
transition-property: translateY, skew;
transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s; 
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease;
transition-delay: 0.02s;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-210%) skew(60deg); 
-moz-transform: translateY(-210%) skew(60deg);
-ms-transform: translateY(-210%) skew(60deg);  
-o-transform: translateY(-210%) skew(60deg); 
transform: translateY(-210%) skew(60deg);
```

Comment: take a look at compatibility on [here.........](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions)

Comment: @Pranav c Does that mean, I don't need the -ms prefix?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `transform` as transition property. Also, you should pair prefixed properties and values:

```
-prefix-transition-property: -prefix-transform;
transition-property: transform;
```

Also, check browser support for this: http://caniuse.com/#search=transition%7Ctransform Depending on required browser support you can drop some prefixes (most likely all, except `-webkit-`).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RUbXu/1/

Comment: Can you be more specific. Having a hard time understanding exactly what you mean?

Comment: This is pretty match it. I've made a demo for you to see working sample.

Comment: Thank you for the FIDDLE. Umm...so I don't need the -moz and -o prefixes either?

Comment: No, unless you want to support an ancient versions of Firefox and Opera.

Comment: I just checked. Your FIDDLE example doesn't really work in Mozilla and Firefox.

Comment: @Boris your homework will be to fix it based on the information I gave you :)

Answer (score 0):

`transition` should have `transform` in it, not the individual components of the transformation.

Note that the only vendor extension you need at this time is `-webkit-transform`. Check http://caniuse.com/ for compatibility.

Comment: What do you mean exactly. Instead of transition I should use transform?

Comment: What I mean is that it should be `transition-property: transform`